# How to upload file from SharePoint online library to S3 bucket using c#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, console-application

I tried below code and able to upload file in S3 bucket but whenever i open file its show message that its corrupted and file format is not correct but file is getting uploaded

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var password = "XXXXXXXXX";
        var username = "XXXXXXXXXX";
        var Url = "https://Test.sharepoint.com/sites/Test";
        using (var context = new ClientContext(Url))
        {
            var securepass = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                securepass.AppendChar(c);
            }
            //log.LogInformation("C# HTTP");
            SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securepass);
            context.Credentials = credentials;
            Web web = context.Web;
            var file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/test.xlsx");
            context.Load(file);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
      
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(file.Name));
            string myBucketName = "buckettest455"; //your s3 bucket name goes here
            string s3DirectoryName = "justdemodirectory";
            string s3FileName = file.Name;

            AmazonUploader myUploader = new AmazonUploader();
            myUploader.sendMyFileToS3(stream, myBucketName, s3DirectoryName, s3FileName);
        }




    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code sample you provided you are converting the file name (not payload) to a MemoryStream and uploading that. You need to invoke **OpenBinaryStream** on the **SPFile** object and pass the **Value** property of the returned object to your **myUploader** method.

I've updated your code to reflect that change:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var password = "XXXXXXXXX";
    var username = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    var Url = "https://Test.sharepoint.com/sites/Test";
    using (var context = new ClientContext(Url))
    {
        var securepass = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            securepass.AppendChar(c);
        }
        //log.LogInformation("C# HTTP");
        SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securepass);
        context.Credentials = credentials;
        Web web = context.Web;
        var file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/test.xlsx");
        ClientResult<Stream> fileStream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
        context.Load(file);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
  
        //MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(file.Name));
        string myBucketName = "buckettest455"; //your s3 bucket name goes here
        string s3DirectoryName = "justdemodirectory";
        string s3FileName = file.Name;

        AmazonUploader myUploader = new AmazonUploader();
        myUploader.sendMyFileToS3(fileStream.Value, myBucketName, s3DirectoryName, s3FileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked